# Compile java file at runtime and use it got ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, runtime

So I'm trying to send an object of a class that the client have the interface but don't have the implement yet from a server to the client along with the implement of that class for the client to compile at runtime. What I got so far is:

- Sending `Class.java` to client
- Compiled it, got `Class.class` file
- Sending object to client

And I got `ClassNotFoundException` here, even though the compiling of the file I just send work just fine. Anyone know what else do I have to do after compiled the file for the client to accept the newly compiled class as one of it's own?

As for the code

```
// sending file over via socket and saved it as Class.java
String fileName = "C:\\Users\\A\\workspace\\Project\\src\\Class.java";
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int result = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileName);
if(result == 0) {
    System.out.println("compiler success"); // just to check if the compiler is fine
}

URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("C:\\Users\\A\\workspace\\Project\\src").toURI().toURL()});
Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("Class");

ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object returnObj = loadedClass.cast(is.readObject()); // got ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
```

Comment: This may be a conflict with java.lang.Class. You should use a package, never put classes in the default package.

Comment: @Patrick I change it to ComputeClass and set package, still same error. But thanks for the reminder on package, I havent do Java in a long time

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `ClassLoader` when deserializing the object. At present, `ObjectInputStream` is using the system class loader, which doesn't have your `Class` available on its classpath.

Setting your classloader as the context class loader may help.

Please change the name of your class, and use packages. You should also investigate the `RMIClassLoader`, which encapsulates many of these operations.

Comment: I can set context class loader by doing `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);`
Before running `ObjectInputStream is = new...` right? that still give me the same `ClassNotFoundException` error.

Comment: Then you're going to have to run your deserialization code in a class that is loaded by your class loader.

Comment: Oh I figure out my problem, cause I run the client using Eclipse, all the source code .class file are compiled into /bin folder, while the compile.run code that I run at runtime only compiled to the same folder as the source code (/src), so the class file that are compiled at run time is in /src too, not /bin with other .class file so it dont work. Just a simple rename the file to change it folder to /bin work just fine. But just to make the code tidier, is there a way to specify so the compiler.run code will put the compiled .class file directly to /bin folder?